# Best way to numerically evaluate derivative of complete elliptic integral 2 kind (C++)

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, improper-integrals, numerical-calculus

I need to compute numerically

$$
\frac{d}{dk}E(k) = \frac{E(k)-K(k)}{k}
$$
where E and K are the complete elliptic integrals of the second and first kind respectively.

Note that Wolfram uses $m=k^2$. In C++ we have these [functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/special_functions/comp_ellint_2). To go from the C++ function to the wolfram function just raise k to 2 in wolfram or take the sqrt root in C++.

I have to compute with accuracy this derivative in the complete domain [0,1], therefore using the representation I put before or central differences do not give good enough results. I also tried a series expansion which works fine for small k, but not for big k.

What is a good way to evaluate this derivative numerically? In this case, I care about performance.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/diff.html

Comment: @caverac, thanks for your answer. But the results are not good. For example, when evaluating in 0, the result should be pi/8 and central differences output 0. Also, for values close to 1 the results vary quite a bit from expected.

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account all your requirements, for the computation of
$$\frac{d}{dk}E(k) = \frac{E(k)-K(k)}{k}$$what I should use is a spline function for
$$g(k)=\exp\Big[E(k)-K(k) \Big]$$ which is a nice and smooth function.

You only need one creation of this spline (or any other interpolating function).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you explain a bit more? How would I use g(x)? Ist not clear to me why a spline of exp(E-K) would help.

Comment: Did you plot $g(k)$ ?